# Problem creating a webpage in OOP pattern?

Tags: php

I  want to develop a website in OOP pattern, but I am stuck in a point whether I need to inherit from multiple classes.

For example
I have a main class "index"
this class has several methods which need to inherited from other classes and I have created seperate classes for it like

class "banner", class "content", class "footer"

Not only this but class "content" has several methods to be inherited from other classes like

class "gallery", class "news", etc

I found out that multiple inheritance is not allowed, and using interface I cannot write codes in its methods, so how can i achieve a solution for this problem.

Comment: OOP stands for object-oriented programming, not object-oriented presentation.

Comment: you mean to say OOP cannot be used to present a webpage?

Comment: @john, Yes john i am working on it. funny I didn't know about that. I apologize to those who have answered my question for my stupidity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a main abstract class http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php which is similar to interface but allows you to add code to the functions. This can include methods that are similar to gallery, news etc

class Gallery extends AbstractClass {}

Comment: No. class content needs to extends from gallery and news class like class gallery extends abstractclassgallery,abstractclassnews { }

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of the functionality of the classes, but just a thought:

```
class Index {
...
}

class Content extends Index {
...
}

class News extends Content {
...
}
```

If the contexts of those classes don't fit, you might want to re-think about the design and functionality of your classes.

**EDIT**

I don't want to come across brash, but if you can't figure out a good inheritance / design pattern maybe you should stick to a well thought out, already existing framework?

Comment: Yes, I was using the chaining pattern like yours, but I came across problem when the classes i am chaining has others chaing also.  I think you understood what I am trying to achieve here, Is there a simple way for this, rather than going for a different framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think of it as a Page object contains several controls (header, footer, content) which themselves can contain controls (News) which can contain controls (text, label, picture) etc...

Comment: Controls is another base class that implements a control interface (you define), and your different controls (header, footer, banner) extend.  Your page, is effectively just a container for controls.  And since controls can contain other controls.  Your page too, is just another extension upon control.

Comment: I am not a PHP expert, so could you please post a example of these controls